# KivyMD и Buildozer.spec

Tags: python, mysql, kivymd, buildozer

Всем привет! Наблюдается вылет скомпелированного приложения .apk (python 3.9+kiviMD) при импорте в main.py виджета KivyMD "MDDatePicker".

```
#main.py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from settings import *
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
```

Если убрать из кода from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker то все работает, приложение .apk не вылетает.

```
#Buildozer.spec:

requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,mysql-connector- 
python==8.0.32
```

Comment: тег пайтон добавьте

Comment: Вобщем конфликт вызывает только модуль MDDatePicker и "from settings import *" (импорт переменных .env)